# Integrating Google Maps with an Android application - fragments issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am struggling to integrate Google Maps with my Android application. What am i doing wrong?

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.theglasgowhive.hive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.theglasgowhive.hive.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I figured it out, it had to be "class" AND there were errors in AndroidManifest (I put meta-data tag in a wrong place...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Comment: "unknown attribute android:class"

Comment: Sorry, it should be class not android:class.

Comment: is that helped you or not? if yes please mark answer as correct.